# "the matrix, M" Vs "M matrix"

Tags: sentence-construction, mathematics, terminology

I would like to understand how to refer to a given matrix in my English sentence.

> The matrix, M, refers to model A.

or

> M matrix refers to model A.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred phrasing is

> The matrix **M** refers to model A

without commas, but with appropriate typesetting if possible. (Boldface upper case is common, but see also [Matrix (mathematics) - Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Notation) on Wikipedia).

Comment: In physics, in quantum field theory, the S-matrix is defined as the unitary matrix connecting sets of asymptotically free particle states in the Hilbert space of physical states. S is for 'scattering'.

Comment: I would not say that is the *preferred* phrasing. It depends on what you're trying to express. If *M* is nonrestrictive information, then, contrarily, the use of paired commas (or parentheses or dashes) is not only the preferred phrasing but *required* in terms of matching syntax to semantics. What might be preferred is if you provide *M* as restrictive rather nonrestrictive.